# accessing two list elements to get results

Tags: python

I have two lists. One list name 'date' has dates in it which are related to persons birth date.

```
data = [ datetime.datetime(1958, 3, 15, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(1958, 9, 15, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(1930, 10, 23, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(1928, 9, 15, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(1928, 1, 23, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(1925, 11, 15, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(1962, 7, 20, 0, 0),datetime.datetime(1960, 12, 14, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(1960, 5, 10, 0, 0),datetime.datetime(1963, 9, 7, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(1956, 3, 10, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(1955, 2, 15, 0, 0),datetime.datetime(1958, 11, 14, 0, 0),datetime.datetime(1956, 8, 24, 0, 0),datetime.datetime(1990, 4, 30, 0, 0)]
```

Now next list contains marriage dates.

```
marriage = [ datetime.datetime(1985, 5, 14, 0, 0),datetime.datetime(1945, 6, 15, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(1938, 6, 11, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(1995, 4, 5, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(1987, 2, 26, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(1983, 12, 13, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(1980, 9, 16, 0, 0),  datetime.datetime(2011, 6, 19, 0, 0)]
```

each date from the 'marriage' list is related to 2 dates from 'date' list. Now, I want to compare one date from marriage list to two dates from date list so that i can print"birth date is less than marriage.

How can accomplish this task using loop? confused with this one.

Please note that I used  import datetime, import re to accomplish date comparison.

Comment: Wow, that code is unreadable. Consider using more than one line.

Comment: How do you know which dates you want to compare?

Comment: `import datetime,re` does the same thing in one line

Comment: I want to compare one date from marriage with two dates from date.All dates from both lists are in sequence.

Comment: Siddharth, Can you comment on what my solution below fails to address? I don't think I'm understanding your problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for i in range(len(data)):
  if data[i] < marriage[i]:
    print "birthdate is lt marriage date"
  else:
    print "birthdate is gt or eq to marriage date"
```

I'm not sure what you are trying to accomplish here... Also you don't need re for date comparison, you can use normal `< > == <= >=` operators.

This also sounds like a job for a hash(dictionary)...

```
marriage = {
    'marriage1' : {
        '1' : <birthday>,
        '2' : <birthday>,
        'marriage-date' : <marriage-date>
    },
   'marriage2' : {
        '1' : <birthday>,
        '2' : <birthday>,
        'marriage-date' : <marriage-date>
    }
}
```

A hash(dictionary) will make comparisons much easier with lists that don't contain the same number of values.

Comment: i want to compare 2 dates from date list with one date from marriage. Your method is not working as i want

Comment: What is the result you want from this comparison? Do you want to see if the birthdates are earlier in the year?

Comment: i want to compare marriage date is greater than birth date

Comment: Do you want to compare the birthdates as a sum or individually? Shouldn't the marriage date always be greater than the birthdate?

Answer (score -1):

This assumes that the marriage and birth dates are in the same order (i.e., the first two birth dates correspond to the first marriage date and the next 2 birth dates correspond to the second marriage date)

```
for i in range(len(marriage)):
    if marriage[i] > data[i*2] and marriage[i] > data[(i*2)+1]:
        print "Both birthdates less than marriage data"
```

I believe my assumption is correct because there are twice as many entries in the data list as there are in the marriage list.